# How to add right click format option to a disk icon in the launcher?

Tags: launcher

How can I add the format option when right clicking in the icon of a disk in the Launcher? Ubuntu 12.04 has this option. How can I make this in Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions`

Search `nautlilus-actions` in the dash

Open it

### Enter the information as follows:

**Action Tab**

Nautilus Item - mark `Display Item in selection context menu`

Context Label - Format Disk

ToolTip - Format Removable USB & SD Media

Icon - browse to /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/file-manager.png and select (this is 
just what i used, you may choose something different(

Action Properties - Enabled

**Command Tab**

Profile - Default Profile

Command - gksudo gnome-format

Parmeters - Blank

**Folders Tab**

Should already have / listed

---

Restart your computer

Finally open nautilus and right click any empty space in the directory that you want to format

Select `nautilus actions`

Select `Format Disk`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It seems doesn't work easily under Trusty (and new one?) because it uses gnome-format that is no more in default repository, as we can saw at page : https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-format/

I am looking for an other tools in http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/utils/ but nothing seems replace it.

[nautilus](/questions/tagged/nautilus)[gnome-format](/questions/tagged/gnome-format)